# Can't build webrtc iOS 64bit build

Tags: xcode, command-line, terminal, webrtc

I'm trying to build webrtc for ios on OSX Yosemite from command line and get the error below
Which compiler is being used? Is it possible to change the compiler that
the xcode command line tools use?

c++-apple-4.2: Unable to guess config name for arch arm64

Anyone know why the above error happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now you can with this commands

```
gn gen out/Debug-device --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="x64" is_component_build=false additional_target_cpus=["arm", "arm64"] enable_dsyms=true ios_enable_code_signing = false'
```

ninja -C out/Debug-device rtc_sdk_framework_objc